# Método open() en Python

Tags: python

tengo un pequeño problema con open(). Como saben, podemos colocar argumentos que indican si abrimos un archivo externo en modo escritura, lectura u otro:

```
from io import open
archivo=open("Archivo_1.txt", "w")  #Escritura.

from io import open
archivo=open("Archivo_1.txt", "r")  #Lectura.
```

Sin embargo, por lo que me explicaron (muy a la brevedad), también podemos abrir/crear un archivo con un argumento que nos permita realizar lectura y escritura:

```
from io import open
archivo=open("Archivo_1.txt", "r+")
```

Pero, parece que no funciona, puesto a que si quiero escribir strings en este me dará error:

```
from io import open
archivo=open("Archivo_1.txt", "r+")
add="fsefsdg"
archivo.write(add)
```

En consola:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pruebas 2.py", line 2, in <module>
    archivo=open("Archivo_1.txt", "r+")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Archivo_1.txt'

***Repl Closed***
```

Esto es fácil de solucionar, pero me parece algo rústico, puesto a que coloco modo escritura y ahí sí, se crea el archivo. También ocurre otro problema, si utilizo el método `write()` y debajo/seguido del mismo utilizo la función `print(archivo.read())` no se imprimirá nada, pero sí cuando este está antes que `write()` en el flujo de ejecución:

```
from io import open
archivo=open("Archivo_1.txt", "r+")
add="fsefsdg"
archivo.write(add)
print(archivo.read())
```

En consola nada...

Pero si quito write() o lo coloco después de read() sí funciona:

```
from io import open
archivo=open("Archivo_1.txt", "r+")
print(archivo.read())
```

En consola:

```
fsefsdg

***Repl Closed***
```

¿Alguien sabe que estoy haciendo mal?, ¿O quizá me explicaron mal la función de r+? Desde ya muchísimas gracias...

Comment: es `w+`, no `r+`, si estás creando un archivo nuevo no se supone que lo necesites leer, porque todo lo que escribes ya lo estás haciendo en tu script, no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El error está claro, el archivo que intentas acceder no existe. Quizás deberías aclarar en qué directorio estas trabajando y si estas saltando entre una consola y un editor, pues podría ocurrir que el editor y la consola estén en rutas distintas y estés creando archivos en distinto lugares.

Otra cosa es que la función `open()`es un "built-in" de Python, significa que no tienes que importar nada porque ya está integrada y que puedes usarla directamente como una más. Así que puedes ahorrarte `from io import open`

Una manera habitual y eficiente de trabajar con `open()` es usar un `Context Manager`:

```
with open("texto.txt", "w") as archivo:
    archivo.write("Hola mundo!")
```

Esto te asegura que instancia un objeto `archivo` que tiene todos los métodos de `open()` con el "extra" de que se encarga de "recoger la cocina" cuando terminas. Esto es, de cerrar el objeto y hacer lo que necesite para asegurarse de que el archivo se guarda correctamente. Si no, tienes que asegurarte de cerrar el objeto con `.close()`

Ten en cuenta que `with...as :` funciona de forma anidada, como si fuese una función o un bucle, cuando termina su contenido, cierra el objeto (en este ejemplo sería `archivo`)

Si quisieras leer un archivo de texto y almacenar su contenido en una variable para más tarde podrías hacer esto:

```
var_texto = ""

with open("texto.txt", "r") as archivo:
    var_texto = archivo.read()

print(var_texto)
- "Hola mundo!"
```

Espero que te haya aclarado un poco más la duda. Un saludo